# OSL shader issue, could not find include file: node_texture.h"

Tags: osl

I am trying to (re)create an [OSL shader](https://github.com/sambler/osl-shaders/blob/master/stone/SARock/SARock.osl) in Blender, but I receive an error "error: could not find include file: node_texture.h" when compiling.

I've Googled it up, but can find nothing. Where can I find this file, or change the search path?

Comment: you should have that file too in your directory

Comment: @Chebhou could you provide a little more detail on your answer?

Comment: go to this link [http://www.openshading.com/osl/example-shaders/#] and download the example_shaders put the file that you need (node_texture.h) with your osl script file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change happened before 2.72 was released and I still haven't got around to looking into whether the change came from blender or OSL 1.5. It is a matter of search paths and I think they need to be changed in code.

The file you are looking for is included with blender, it is installed in `2.72/scripts/addons/cycles/shader/` You can also find it in blender's source tree at [`intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_texture.h`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_texture.h)

The solution for now is to place a copy of it in the same folder as the osl script that wants to include it.

Comment: Thanks @sambler! That was the solution. Also, thanks for sharing your code and knowledge. I copied and pasted the  node_texture.h file into the appropriate folder.